# Cannot read property 'ping' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, ping, defined

```
const client = require('../index.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'latency',
    aliases: ['lat'],
    description: 'Let the Bot display your latency.',
    execute(message, args) {
        const m = message.channel.send("Pinging...");
            m.edit(`Your latency latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms.\nAPI Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
            message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
                return
    }
        
};
```

So it sends "Pinging" but then I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'ping' of undefined
```

and I don't know how or where I should define ping, does someone know?

Comment: Couple of things. Make the path of import `const client = require('../index.js');` is correct.
Aldo verify if `client.ws` is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems like it's being caused by the way you're importing `client`, the best thing to do to fix your issue is by passing `client` in your `execute()` function in your command files and in your `index.js`